# Facebook Page plugin not accepting my page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to do the Facebook page plugin to a site of mine and anytime I enter my page URL, I get this code from Facebook - Error: Not a valid Facebook Page url.

I am copying and pasting the URL right from my profile page. I tried this on several other of my friends pages and I keep getting the same error. I get this error on the Facebook developer page and on my site.

I am using this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

I went to Social Plugins and then Page plugin. I then typed the URL in the Facebook Page URL input field. It is supposed to show a preview of the page plugin, but I continuously only get the error.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**profile != page**

A user profile and a Facebook page are two different things.

The plugin works for pages only, not for user profiles.

Comment: What do you mean page? Do you mean groups? I just tried a groups url and it does not work as well.

Comment: Gotcha! Do you know if there is a way to make this work for a user profile or group?

Comment: No, Facebook doesn’t offer any plugin for that. If you want to display data from a profile or a group on an external site, you would need to get that data via API first, and then take care of outputting it in an appropriate HTML structure yourself.